# matrices with determinant equals to one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition

we already know what does it mean the determinant of a matrix is null, it's not invertible ! but what about matrices with determinant equals to $1$ ?! I know that the determinant of matrix is the volume of the polyhedron build from the rows of the matrix (or the columns) but what does it mean a unit volume, I mean is there any mathematical aspect represents this fact just like the invertibility ? Thank you for your time .

Comment: Well, they form a group, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group

Comment: Said matrices are volume-preserving transformations on Euclidean space.

Answer (score 4):

For a [coordinate transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations) $x_i \to x_i'$ the determinant of the matrix of the partial derivatives gives the correction factor for the volumes:
$$
dV = dx_1 \cdots dx_n
= \mbox{det } \left(
\frac{\partial(x_1, \ldots x_n)}{\partial(x_1', \ldots, x_n')} \right)
dx_1' \cdots dx_n' = \mbox{det }(J) \, dV'
$$
where $J$ is called the Jacobian matrix, with $J_{ij} = \partial x_i/\partial x_j'$.

If $\mbox{det}(J) = 1$ then $dV = dV'$, so for these transformations the volumes are invariant.

Comment: @MattSamuel, but the op has accepted the answer for one. the more constructive approach would be for you to write a  response if you think you have a better answer. what is the point in demanding mvw to write an ansewr to your liking.

Comment: I updated thanks to @MattSamuel, that was constructive.